# new objects are automaticlly locking together

Tags: objects

I am on a layer, I make a dup object, it gets locked to the original one. I do it again, I make an object, then a brand new one to size it smaller to put it inside of it instead, as soon as it touches it they become one object, stuck together. put a different object in to see what that would do ,as soon as I put it in contact with the first object it to is now locked together, I tried using 'U' on the duplicate object "shift D" it did not separate them either. 
layer 10 on the first set of layers,

[image]

Comment: The objects move together as you have [proportional editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5199/935) enabled. They snap together from the [snapping settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39787/935)

Comment: thanks, I knew it had to be something simple, just didn't know what. thanks again, now I can move on with this. @sambler