# When I rotate A mesh, B mesh will rotate too, but I don't want it, how can i do?

Tags: mesh, transforms, linked-data

I made 2 mesh（cylinder.001 & cylinder.000, separate mesh）, the inside mesh is made by duplicating the outside mesh. After that , when i rotate one of the 2 meshes ,the other one will rotate too. I don't know why? how can I cancel the link between two meshes?

Hope someone can help me to solve this problem ,thanks[image]

[image: separate mesh]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nearby objects won't move independently?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/nearby-objects-wont-move-independently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disable the *Proportional Editing* option

[image]