# Impossible to move the camera without my object moving too

Tags: camera

I have a torus mesh and a camera I want to move the camera to have a better render. But the problem is, when I click on my camera and press G to move it, the camera seems to be attached to my mesh and moove with it.
How can I fix this?

Best regards,
Wyno
(PS : I already try to look into the view settings/properties and the local camera is my camera and not my mesh)
[image]

[image]

Comment: for the donut (mesh), is there any modifiers in the Object *Constraint Properties* (tab)?  You might consider sharing your file with [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/)  copy and paste the HTML text into your question in edit mode.

Comment: Hi, thx for the reply, I already checked my modifiers and applied them all, for the donut and the icing. I added my file in the post

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/nearby-objects-wont-move-independently https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/why-cant-i-transform-faces-edges-or-vertices-without-transforming-the-whole-o

Answer (score 0):

Disable the *Proportional Editing* option, otherwise all the objects that are adjacent to the selected one (and within the influence radius) will move with it:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!