Imported Object (.obj) linked to existing objects in Scene
I am importing an object to an existing scene made up of objects in Blender. When i bring in the new object..it comes in selected (highlighted). I click away from it to unselect it. Then select it again and press G to move it to somewhere else in the scene.
The problem I am having is that this imported .obj object moves some (but not all) of the other objects that were preexisted in the scene before the import. I don't want this. I want my imported object to move independently. Please help.

Hello, could you please show a screenshot? Have enabled the Proportional Editing option (top bar)?

I just now was able to prevent it from happening by making the other objects unselectable in the outliner panel. Thank you, however, for your willingness to help.

Mmh it's still not clear what your problem is

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/nearby-objects-wont-move-independently https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27394/why-cant-i-transform-faces-edges-or-vertices-without-transforming-the-whole-o/27395#27395
